# How to compare elements in list-of-lists?

Tags: python, list, python-zip

I have a list which contains list of elements(the number of elements in each inner list are not same) and I want to group all the elements in same index into separate groups and return maximum values in each group:
for example,

```
elements = [[89, 213, 317], [106, 191, 314], [87]]
```

I want to group these elements like this,

```
groups = [[89,106,87],[213,191],[317,314]]
```

the expected result is the maximum values of each list in groups : 106 ,213 and 317

I tried to group elements using following code:

```
w = zip(*elements)
result_list = list(w)
print(result_list)
```

output I got  is

```
[(89, 106, 87)]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest) with `fillvalue=float("-inf")`:

```py
from itertools import zip_longest

elements = [[89, 213, 317], [106, 191, 314], [87]]

out = [max(t) for t in zip_longest(*elements, fillvalue=float("-inf"))]
print(out)
```

Prints:

```py
[106, 213, 317]
```

---

NOTE: `zip()` won't work here, because (as you stated) the number of elements in each inner list are not same. With `zip_longest()` the missing elements are substituted with `fillvalue`, in this case `-infinity` (and `-infinity` will be always the lowest value in the `max()` function)

Answer (score 2):

Try creating a dictionary keyed with the index of each sub list, then turning the `values` into the new list, then map to max:

```
from collections import defaultdict

elements = [[89, 213, 317], [106, 191, 314], [87]]

i_d = defaultdict(list)

for sub in elements:
    for i, v in enumerate(sub):
        i_d[i].append(v)

maxes = list(map(max, i_d.values()))
print(maxes)
```

`i_d`:

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {0: [89, 106, 87], 1: [213, 191], 2: [317, 314]})
```

`maxes`:

```
[106, 213, 317]
```